# Copy an Array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, copy

Why the range to be copied does not include the array element at final index?

Example:

```
class ArrayCopyOfDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {  

        char[] copyFrom = {'d', 'e', 'c', 'a', 'f', 'f', 'e',
            'i', 'n', 'a', 't', 'e', 'd'};

        char[] copyTo = java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(copyFrom, 2, 9);

        System.out.println(new String(copyTo));
    }
}
```

Results: "caffein"

(The range to be copied does not include the array element at index 9 (which contains the character a).

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Thank you very much for your answers!

Comment: This is pretty consistent with all Java ranges, the starting index is included while the end is not. See also `String.substring` for instance, etc. etc.

Comment: Because that's how the method works... https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(char[],%20int,%20int)

Comment: It already tells you why in the link you posted: "Note that the **second parameter** of the copyOfRange method is the initial index of the range to be copied, **inclusively**, while the **third parameter** is the final index of the range to be copied, **exclusively**."

Comment: The person asked a question, the person may not understand the documentation, rather than hitting out on them about not knowing the documentation, just explain the solution if any.

Comment: It also makes it easier to do `copyOfRange(source, start, start + length)`

Answer (score 4):

From Arrays.copyOfRange javadoc:

```
 * @param from the initial index of the range to be copied, inclusive
 * @param to the final index of the range to be copied, exclusive.
```

Answer (score 0):

The Arrays.copyOfRange method will copy from (i, j-1). Your line should be

```
char[] copyTo = java.util.Arrays.copyOfRange(copyFrom, 2, 10);
```

to include the final character.